# how to save RDS file with different title in r?

Tags: r

I have want to save the cars data in a loop with different title name.

```
for (i in 1:10)
{ outfilename=paste0(i ,".RDS")
saveRDS(cars, file = "/home/outfilename.RDS")}
```

however, it looks like the out filename still did not work

Comment: for (i in 1:10){saveRDS(cars, file = paste0("/home/", i ,".RDS"))}

Comment: @VasilyA Feel free to post as answer, that resolves the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant something like this:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  outfilename <- paste0("/home/", i ,".RDS")
  saveRDS(cars, file = outfilename)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `lapply`

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) 
  saveRDS(cars, file = file.path('/home', paste0(i, ".RDS"))))
```